# Can you give me feedback on a small python refactor

Tags: python, refactoring, code-snippets

I've a small snippet of python code and i'm trying to refactor a block, how could i approach this problem?

```
def function():
    samples = []
    for i in samples:
        if i == 1:
             # custom stuff due to i = 1
             # generic stuff A
             # generic stuff B
             # generic stuff C
        if i == 2:
             # custom stuff due to i = 2
             # generic stuff A
             # generic stuff B
             # generic stuff C
        if i == 3:
             # custom stuff due to i = 3
             # generic stuff A
             # generic stuff B
             # generic stuff C
        if i == 4:
             # custom stuff due to i = 4
             # generic stuff A
             # generic stuff B
             # generic stuff C
```

I came up with this alternative:

```
def function():
    samples = []
    for i in samples:
        if i == 1:
             # custom stuff due to i = 1
        if i == 2:
             # custom stuff due to i = 2
        if i == 3:
             # custom stuff due to i = 3
        if i == 4:
             # custom stuff due to i = 4
        # generic stuff A
        # generic stuff B
        # generic stuff C
```

Is this an alternative? Im new to refactoring

Comment: I'd use an `elif` for checking all the other values. if it equals one of them, it doesn't need to check the rest of the statements which will save some computing time. i'd also rename `i` to be something a bit more descriptive, but other than that, without knowing exactly what the generic stuff are, you've pretty much got it

Comment: I mean no disrespect, but this refactor is so extremely obvious (basic DRY) that I don't really see what the question here is. That's further evidenced by the first comment, which focuses on an actual issue with your code (that wasn't part of the refactor). Regardless, code reviews aren't really for StackOverflow, you should consider posting here instead https://codereview.stackexchange.com/  (issues: `samples` is empty, and you're not saying how the "custom stuff" relates to `i`; does "generic stuff" need to happen as many times as there are samples?)

Comment: Thanks Grismar, i will check codereview!

Comment: @David, this question is not at all suited to [codereview.se], which requires _concrete_ code from a project, not obfuscated/example code such as this. You should have pointed the asker at [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778), as some things are done differently over there - e.g. we need a good description of the *purpose* of the code, and question titles should simply say what the code *does* (the question is always, "_How can I improve this?_").  It's important that the code works correctly; include the unit tests if possible.

Comment: @TobySpeight - agreed, and deleted my close-vote comment. 99% of the time, I suggest reading the specific site's guidelines when redirecting someone to another SO site, prior to just reposting somewhere else. I failed to do that this time.